# Textfield array and while loop

Tags: php, html

I if have inputs like this one, but those 2 inputs are repeating themselves multiple times. So it could be:

```
    <input name="Gpodaciogolubu[]" type="text">
    <input name="Gpodaciogolubu_godina[]" type="number">

    <input name="Gpodaciogolubu[]" type="text">
    <input name="Gpodaciogolubu_godina[]" type="number">

    <input name="Gpodaciogolubu[]" type="text">
    <input name="Gpodaciogolubu_godina[]" type="number">
...
```

Is it possible to use while or foreach loop to get both values at the same time and insert it both in database like:

```
"INSERT INTO database (field1, filed2) VALUES ('$_POST["Gpodaciogolubu"]','$_POST["Gpodaciogolubu_godina"]')"
```

I'm coding in PHP/MySQL

Comment: This question is incomplete.  What language are you coding with?  What's the repetition that you're talking about?

Comment: I added more info. I hope it helps

Comment: I changed your tags to ones that people are actually following.  That should help.

Comment: Whilst not specifically relevant, you *really* need to ensure you're not enabling SQL injection when you insert the data into the database. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php for more info.

Comment: I know. I'm checking all what is being input with function and mysqli_escape_strng

Answer (score 0):

First build an array of rows to insert:

```
$rows = []; // or array() in PHP 5.3 and older
$l = count($_POST['Gpodaciofolubu']);
for( $i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
    $rows[] = "("
        ."'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Gpodaciofolubu'][$i])."', "
        .intval($_POST['Gpodaciofolubu_godina'][$i]) // since you have `type="number"`
    .")";
}
```

Then batch insert them:

```
mysql_query("insert into `database` (`field1`, `field2`) values ".implode(",",$rows));
```

This assumes, of course, that you're using the `mysql` extension. This assumption is based on the complete lack of any attempt to sanitize your input.

[image: xkcd]